# How to fit exponential and Poisson distributions to table of event times in R?

Tags: poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution, interarrival-time

I have a vector of event dates where multiple events can occur on the same date. I have sorted these dates in chronological order and have also generated a table of times between events.

Here is an example of the data:

```
> table(table(sorted))

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  28  31 
369 167 202 278 338 390 400 440 411 313 278 273 182 154 109  94  69  49  32  18  17   8   6   1   6   2   1   1
```

The first row is the number of events occurring on a single day, the second row is the frequency of that number of events occurring on a single day.

I also have inter-event times:

```
> table(gaps)
gaps
    0     1     2     3     4     5 
32966  3752   327   499    26     3
```

What I would like to do is fit an exponential distribution to the inter-event table and a Poisson distribution to the number of events data. I will then use these distributions to generate randomised number of events and/or inter-event times.

I have tried using `fitdist` as follows:

```
> fitdist(as.vector(table(table(sorted))), "exp")
Fitting of the distribution ' exp ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
        estimate  Std. Error
rate 0.006076389 0.001116184

> fitdist(as.vector(table(table(sorted))), "pois")
Fitting of the distribution ' pois ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
       estimate Std. Error
lambda 164.5714   2.424366
```

However I'm unsure if I have used the function correctly, or how to use the lambda and rate parameters that have been calculated. Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `fitdist` is the wrong tool.  The problem you describe is to *estimate* the parameter of the model: namely, either the Poisson parameter or the Exponential rate (they would be equal).